# При настройке ADOTable на PostgreSQL выходит сообщение, что таблица не найдена

Tags: postgresql, delphi, ado, delphi-11-alexandria

Настраиваю в Delphi 11 через ADO подключение к БД PostgreSQL. Подключение к схеме public - без проблем, к другой же схеме подключается, выводится даже список таблиц. При настройке ADOTable выбираю нужную таблицу, перевожу в активное состояние и выходит сообщение, что таблица не найдена.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить схему в подключении?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят. Переделал подключение через FireDAC.

Там в FDTable есть свойство SchemaName.